# H2 access denied

Tags: spring-security, h2

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
  private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .headers()
            .frameOptions().disable()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

I have this config class. I placed `.requestMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()` in the code but when I visit the `http://localhost:8080/h2` I take:

> Access to localhost was denied

the JwtAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if (authHeader == null ||!authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The doFilterInternal method is the main method of the filter. It checks if the incoming request has an "Authorization" header with a JWT starting with "Bearer ", and if so, extracts the user email from the JWT using the JwtService and loads the user details using the UserDetailsService. If the JWT is valid and the user details are successfully loaded, an Authentication object is created and set in the SecurityContextHolder. The filter chain is then continued with the filterChain.doFilter(request, response) call.

Comment: It is propably your `jwtAuthFilter`. Show your implementation of `JwtAuthenticationFilter `. However, try `http://localhost:8080/h2/` first. Maybe it is only the missing `/`.

Comment: please do not post images of code, it is forbidden, read the rules of stack overflow and use the edit button on your question

Answer (score 0):

`.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2/**")).permitAll()` instead of : `.requestMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()`